# how to get all stored procedure execution time , cup time etc

Tags: sql-server, database, stored-procedures, database-performance

```
 SELECT DB_NAME(st.dbid) DBName
      ,OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(objectid,st.dbid) SchemaName
      ,OBJECT_NAME(objectid,st.dbid) StoredProcedure
      ,max(cp.usecounts) execution_count
      ,sum(qs.total_elapsed_time) total_elapsed_time
      ,sum(qs.total_elapsed_time) / max(cp.usecounts) avg_elapsed_time
 FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats qs CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.plan_handle) st
   join sys.dm_exec_cached_plans cp on qs.plan_handle = cp.plan_handle
 where  cp.objtype = 'proc'
 group by DB_NAME(st.dbid),OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(objectid,st.dbid), OBJECT_NAME(objectid,st.dbid) 
 order by sum(qs.total_elapsed_time) desc
```

I am running above query but not able to find all SP list details which are created in database.
It shows only fewer SP.

Please help me.
Waiting for your valuable reply.

Comment: Not every stored procedure will have an entry in sys.dm_exec_cached_plans

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this, a lot more complicated but it gets around the fact that not every stored procedure will have statistics:

```
CREATE TABLE #x(
    database_id INT, 
    DatabaseName SYSNAME, 
    SchemaName SYSNAME, 
    ProcedureName SYSNAME, 
    [object_id] INT);
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';
SELECT 
    @sql = @sql + N'INSERT INTO #x SELECT ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), d.database_id) + ', ''' + name + ''', s.name, p.name, p.[object_id]
    FROM ' + QUOTENAME(d.name) + '.sys.schemas AS s
    INNER JOIN ' + QUOTENAME(d.name) + '.sys.procedures AS p ON p.schema_id = s.schema_id;' FROM sys.databases d WHERE d.database_id > 4;
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;

WITH PlanData AS (
SELECT
    st.[dbid] AS database_id,
    st.objectid AS [object_id],
    DB_NAME(st.[dbid]) AS DBName,
    OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(st.objectid, st.[dbid]) AS SchemaName,
    OBJECT_NAME(st.objectid, st.[dbid]) AS StoredProcedure,
    MAX(cp.usecounts) AS execution_count,
    SUM(qs.total_elapsed_time) AS total_elapsed_time,
    SUM(qs.total_elapsed_time) / MAX(cp.usecounts) AS avg_elapsed_time
 FROM
    sys.dm_exec_query_stats qs
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.plan_handle) st
    LEFT JOIN sys.dm_exec_cached_plans cp on cp.plan_handle = qs.plan_handle
WHERE
    cp.objtype = 'PROC'
GROUP BY
    st.[dbid],
    st.objectid,
    DB_NAME(st.[dbid]),
    OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(st.objectid, st.[dbid]), 
    OBJECT_NAME(st.objectid, st.[dbid]))
SELECT 
    x.DatabaseName,
    x.SchemaName,
    x.ProcedureName,
    pd.execution_count,
    pd.total_elapsed_time,
    pd.avg_elapsed_time
FROM 
    #x x
    LEFT JOIN PlanData pd ON pd.database_id = x.database_id AND pd.[object_id] = x.[object_id];
DROP TABLE #x;
```

From MSDN regarding sys.dm_exec_query_stats, "The view contains one row per query statement within the cached plan, and the lifetime of the rows are tied to the plan itself. When a plan is removed from the cache, the corresponding rows are eliminated from this view."